# PHP - cooler function parameter

Tags: php, variables, function

I have this:

```
function boo($show_one = false){
  if(!show_one) return 1; else return 2;
}
```

how can I call boo like this:

```
boo(SHOW_ALL);
```

instead of boo(false).
I see some native php function have parameters like that which make the code more easy to read

Comment: That code will always return 2. The function body should read `  return $show_one ? 1 : 2;`. Also note that you forgot the `$` before `showOne` and that will make PHP think it is a constant. But since it is an undefined constant, PHP will assume you meant the string 'show_one', which - when evaluated in a boolean context, will be TRUE.

Comment: On a sidenote, you should not introduce unnecessary constants for the sake of coolness. If that function can accept a boolean, [keep it simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and pass in a Boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
define("SHOW_ALL", false);
define("SHOW_ONE", true);
```

would correspond to your code there. But I'd reccomend using numbers instead of booleans. What if next weeks you decide to have a SHOW_PAGINATED option?

Comment: oh i see now, they are called constants. tx.
another question: do I have to worry about naming conflicts with default PHP defines?

Comment: I would imagine so. Don't do define("STRING", whatever). It might work, but it's a bad idea. Though most inbuilt constants are of the form MODULE_NAME_OF_CONSTANT iirc.

Answer (score 0):

```
define('SHOW_ALL', true);

function boo($show_one = false){
  if(!$show_one) return 1; else return 2;
}

boo(SHOW_ALL);
```